# UML: how to represent use case extension for two actors

Tags: uml

Imagine you have one use case "register contract" and one extension "attach document". The two actors are not related at all (I mean, one of them do not extend the other one); both can register a contract but only the "client" can also attach documents.

How do you represent that? Is my example right or should I trace a line from the client to the "register contract" use case too?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would use two diagrams, one per actor

Answer (score 0):

Create two different use cases, one for the employee ("register contract") and one for the client, and in the client ("extended register contact" or something like that). If you want to show that both use cases are related you can add use inheritance between them.

Another option is to add a parent to both client and employee inherit from a common parent which activates the use case, and add a comment to the `<<extends>>` link stating that the extension can only be called if the caller is a client (see the example shown [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams.html#extend))

Comment: Thanks. I don't like the first alternative because it does not reflect that the only difference between both use cases is the file attachment. I prefer the second approach, but I will probably use the solution proposed by @Jaime, as it seems easier to be understood.